# Create Facebook Event with python's urllib2 library

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, urllib2

I'm trying to create an `event` with facebook from an external application. I've read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events) con events, where it states that you can create an event via POST, so i have the following-

```
data = dict()
data['access_token'] = self.access_token
data['name'] = 'Fb event from Python!'
data['start_time'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
data = urllib.urlencode(data)

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events'
request = urllib2.Request(url=url, data=data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Where I already have my access token and my fb permissions set so my app can create events and so forth. But I get an `error 400 = Bad Request`, so if anyone could help I'd be more than happy thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be curious why aren't you using https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

Comment: I hadn't found that library, thanks for the tip I'll give it a try. I tried using the fb js sdk and that worked like in 2min, but now it got kinda personal so I have to be able to do it with python!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say you should think about using facebook-sdk. From your error i.e http 400 you know that what you are doing wrong is how you are sending the http request itself. The request requires certain parameters in a certain form that you are not giving. If you look at
the request function in [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py#L293)

It makes the request in this form where path is id( I am also not sure me is valid here, but perhaps we can use me for the resource whose access-token we are using)

I think args access token .

```
file = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/" + path + "?" +
                                   urllib.urlencode(args),
                                   post_data, timeout=self.timeout)
```

Thus change the form in which you are making the request. You can go through facebook.py's code and docs to figure out the variables mean based on your needs